# How to append multiple layers to an ArcGIS Online hosted feature layer at once using the ArcGIS API for Python

Tags: python, append, arcgis

I would like to use ArcGIS API for Python to appending new feature layers to an existing hosted FL on AGOL.

The hosted layer (FGDB) on AGOL consisting from 3 layers (two of them are with point geometry and one is layer geometry - pointsA, lines, pointsB).

The goal is append new shapefiles with the same attribute structure like in existing hosted FL (pointsA.shp, lines.shp, pointsB.shp).

Thanks for any kind of help

I tried to use folowing code in Python notebook in arcgis pro:

```
import os
import zipfile
import arcpy
import arcgis

gis = GIS("https://name.maps.arcgis.com", "login", "password")
existing_gdb = gis.content.get('831c85ad90b155SD551D5b43cc4b') # id of hosted FS
print(existing_gdb)


item_prop =  {"title": "new_item", #title - source_table_name
           "type": "Shapefile",
             "tags": "import"}
new_item = gis.content.add (data = r'C:\path\to\new\shapefiles\new_items.zip', item_properties = item_prop)

status = existing_gdb.layers[0].append(item_id=new_item.id, upload_format = 'shapefile', source_table_name='new_item')
print(status)
```

Comment: Depending on your data/workflow, the ArcGIS API for Python's [FeatureLayerCollection.manager.overwrite() method](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.managers.html#arcgis.features.managers.FeatureLayerCollectionManager.overwrite) might be an easier/more straight-forward option.

Answer (score 2):

##### Short answer:

As of version 2.1.0 of the ArcGIS API for Python, there doesn't appear to be an option to append multiple layers at once (the [*FeatureLayerCollection* class](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html#featurelayercollection) doesn't have an append method, only the [*FeatureLayer* class](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html#arcgis.features.FeatureLayer.append)).

##### Long answer:

For starters, let's connect Esri's terminology since it varies slightly between ArcGIS Online, the ArcGIS REST API, and the ArcGIS API for Python:

- In ArcGIS Online, we're talking about a *feature layer* item
- When working with the ArcGIS REST API, we're talking about the [*FeatureService* endpoint](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/feature-service.htm)
- When working with the ArcGIS API for Python, we're talking about the [*FeatureLayerCollection* class](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html#featurelayercollection)

These terms all refer to the same thing. The important thing to recognize is that ArcGIS Online and the ArcGIS API for Python are built on/around the ArcGIS REST API (they're both ways to interface with the ArcGIS REST API, which is the thing behind the scenes that's actually responsible for operations like **append**). With this in mind, I'll use the ArcGIS REST API terminology and refer to the thing that we're appending to as a *FeatureService*.

In the case of **append**, neither ArcGIS Online (as of June 2023) nor the ArcGIS API for Python (as of version `2.1.0`) allow you to append multiple layers to a *FeatureService* at once (the [*FeatureLayerCollection* class](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html#featurelayercollection) doesn't have an append method), but the [ArcGIS REST API does](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/append-feature-service-.htm). You could make your own POST request to ArcGIS REST API's *FeatureService* `append` operation if you need to append all three layers at once:

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.features import FeatureLayerCollection
import requests

gis = GIS("https://arcgis.com", "<username>", "<password>")

hfl_item = gis.content.get("<item id>")

params = {"layers": [0, 1, 2], "layerMappings":[{"id": 0, "sourceTableName": "pointsA"}, {"id": 1, "sourceTableName": "lines"}, {"id": 0, "sourceTableName": "pointsB"}, "upsert": False, "userGlobalIds": False, "appendUploadId": "<itemd id>", "appendUploadformat": "shapefile", "rollbackonFailure": True, "f": "json", "token": gis._con.token]

resp = requests.post(FeatureLayerCollection.fromitem(hfl_item).url, params=params)
```

Alternatively, if you'd prefer to continue using the ArcGIS API for Python, you have to append to each layer of the *FeatureService* individually (note: a layer of a *FeatureService* is called a *Layer* in ArcGIS Online and the [ArcGIS REST API](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/layer-feature-service-.htm) and a *FeatureLayer* in the [ArcGIS API for Python](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html#featurelayer) -- again, all the same thing). You're part way there with `existing_gdb.layers[0].append()`, but this only appends to the first (`0` index layer) of the *FeatureService*. You could easily extend this with a `for`-loop:

```
for layer in existing_gdb.layers:
    layer.append()
```